# Error in file sending program I have written

Tags: vb.net, tcp, file-transfer

Can anyone suggest what is wrong with the following two projects? For some reason it appears as though more bytes are received than sent. Thanks

Code to receive:

```
Imports System.Threading
Imports System.Net
Imports System.Net.Sockets
Imports System.IO

Public Class Form1

    'Dim SumBytes As Integer = 0


    Private Sub Form1_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
        Dim ProcessIt As New Thread(AddressOf Process)
        ProcessIt.IsBackground = True
        ProcessIt.Start()
    End Sub

    Private Sub Process()
        Dim ServerInst As New TcpListener(8000) 'port to receive instructions
        Dim ClientInst As TcpClient

        ServerInst.Start()
        ClientInst = ServerInst.AcceptTcpClient
        Dim netStream As NetworkStream = ClientInst.GetStream
        Dim valid As Boolean = True
        Dim number As Integer 'number of packets
        Dim TotalNumberOfBytes As Integer
        Dim FilePath As String
        Dim portN As ULong

        While valid = True
            Dim buffer(10024 - 1) As Byte
            Dim bytesRead As Integer = netStream.Read(buffer, 0, buffer.Length)

            number = BitConverter.ToInt64(buffer, 0)

            TotalNumberOfBytes = BitConverter.ToUInt64(buffer, 8)

            portN = BitConverter.ToInt64(buffer, 16)

            FilePath = System.Text.Encoding.ASCII.GetString(buffer, 25, buffer(24)) 'filename


            If My.Computer.FileSystem.FileExists("C:\Test" & FilePath) Then
                'Dim info2 As New FileInfo(FolderPath & FilePath)
                'Dim length2 As Long = info2.Length

                'If Math.Ceiling(length2 / 10023) <> number Then
                '    netStream.Flush()
                '    ReDim buffer(10023)
                '    buffer(0) = Math.Ceiling(length2 / 10023)
                '    netStream.Write(buffer, 0, buffer.Length)
                '    Directory.CreateDirectory(Path.GetDirectoryName(FolderPath & FilePath))
                '    writer = New BinaryWriter(System.IO.File.Open(FolderPath & FilePath, FileMode.Append))
                '    ProcessFile(FolderPath & FilePath, netStream, buffer, Math.Ceiling(length2 / 10024), writer)
                'Else
                '    netStream.Flush()
                '    ReDim buffer(10023)
                '    buffer(0) = 0
                '    buffer(1) = 1
                '    netStream.Write(buffer, 0, buffer.Length)
                'End If
            Else
                'netStream.Flush()
                'ReDim buffer(10023)
                'buffer(0) = 0
                'netStream.Write(buffer, 0, buffer.Length)

                Directory.CreateDirectory(Path.GetDirectoryName("C:\Test" & FilePath))
                'writer = New BinaryWriter(System.IO.File.Open(FolderPath & FilePath, FileMode.Create))
                'ProcessFile(FolderPath & FilePath, netStream, buffer, 0, writer)
            End If

            Dim rec As New ReceiveFile(FilePath, 8001, number)

        End While

    End Sub

    Public Class ReceiveFile
        Public Sub New(ByVal FilePath As String, ByVal port As Integer, ByVal numberOfPackets As Integer)
            'Constructor

            Dim ServerInstance As New TcpListener(port) 'port to receive file
            ServerInstance.Start()
            Dim ClientInstance As TcpClient = ServerInstance.AcceptTcpClient
            Dim netStreamInstance As NetworkStream = ClientInstance.GetStream
            Dim Buffer(10034) As Byte
            Dim writer As BinaryWriter = New BinaryWriter(System.IO.File.Open("C:\Test" & FilePath, FileMode.Create))
            Dim count As Integer = 0
            Dim buff2(0) As Byte

            Do While True


                Dim bytesRead As ULong


                Try
                    bytesRead = netStreamInstance.Read(Buffer, 0, Buffer.Length)
                Catch ex As Exception
                    End
                End Try

                If System.Text.Encoding.ASCII.GetString(Buffer, 0, 11) <> "PenSendProc" Then
                    Continue Do
                End If


                Dim BufferData(UBound(Buffer) - 11) As Byte


                For i = 0 To UBound(BufferData)
                    BufferData(i) = Buffer(i + 11)
                Next

                If count = numberOfPackets - 2 Then
                    ReDim Preserve BufferData(bytesRead - 1 - 11)
                    writer.Write(BufferData)
                    netStreamInstance.Write(buff2, 0, buff2.Length)
                    Exit Do
                End If

                writer.Write(BufferData)
                netStreamInstance.Flush()
                netStreamInstance.Write(buff2, 0, buff2.Length)

                count += 1

            Loop

            writer.Close()
            netStreamInstance.Write(buff2, 0, buff2.Length)
            ServerInstance.Stop()
            ClientInstance.Close()
        End Sub
    End Class

End Class
```

Code to send:

```
Imports System.Threading
Imports System.Net
Imports System.Net.Sockets
Imports System.IO

Public Class Form1

    Dim number As ULong
    Dim CancelTimerThread As Boolean
    Dim TimeItThread As Thread
    Dim file As System.IO.StreamWriter
    Dim threadTimeIt As Thread
    Dim NumberOfBytes As ULong
    Dim PortNumber As ULong = 8001


    Private Sub Form1_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
        'Dim SendItClient As New TcpClient
        'SendItClient.Connect("10.0.20.61", 8000)
        'Dim nstm As NetworkStream = SendItClient.GetStream
        'Dim GetFolder As New FolderBrowserDialog
        'GetFolder.ShowDialog()
        'Dim path1 As String
        'path1 = GetFolder.SelectedPath

        'GetBytes(path1)
        'SendEachFileInDir(path1, path1, nstm)
        'SendItClient.Close()
    End Sub


    Private Sub GetBytes(ByVal path As String)


        For Each foundfile As String In My.Computer.FileSystem.GetFiles(path)
            Dim pstm As Stream = New FileStream(foundfile, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read)
            NumberOfBytes += pstm.Length
            pstm.Close()
        Next

        If My.Computer.FileSystem.GetDirectories(path).Count > 0 Then
            For Each Dir As String In My.Computer.FileSystem.GetDirectories(path)
                GetBytes(Dir)
            Next
        End If

    End Sub


    Private Sub SendEachFileInDir(ByVal path As String, ByVal path1 As String, ByVal nstm As NetworkStream)
        For Each foundfile As String In My.Computer.FileSystem.GetFiles(path)
            Dim fstm As Stream = New FileStream(foundfile, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read)
            Dim buffer(10024 - 1) As Byte
            Dim size As ULong  'no of packets
            size = Math.Ceiling(fstm.Length / 10024) + 1

            Dim ByteSize() As Byte = BitConverter.GetBytes(size)
            Dim ByteTotalNumber() As Byte = BitConverter.GetBytes(NumberOfBytes)
            Dim PortNumberBytes() As Byte = BitConverter.GetBytes(PortNumber)
            Dim filenamebytes() As Byte = System.Text.Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(Mid(foundfile, path1.Length + 1))

            Dim SendBytes(UBound(ByteSize) + UBound(filenamebytes) + UBound(ByteTotalNumber) + UBound(PortNumberBytes) + 4) As Byte
            Dim count As Integer = 0

            For i = 0 To UBound(ByteSize)
                SendBytes(count) = ByteSize(i)
                count += 1
            Next

            For i = 0 To UBound(ByteTotalNumber)
                SendBytes(count) = ByteTotalNumber(i)
                count += 1
            Next

            For i = 0 To UBound(PortNumberBytes)
                SendBytes(count) = PortNumberBytes(i)
                count += 1
            Next

            SendBytes(count) = filenamebytes.Length
            count += 1

            For i = 0 To UBound(filenamebytes)
                SendBytes(count) = filenamebytes(i)
                count += 1
            Next

            nstm.Write(SendBytes, 0, SendBytes.Length)

            'ReDim buffer(1023)
            'nstm.Read(buffer, 0, buffer.Length)
            'Dim val As Integer = buffer(0)

            'If val = 0 And buffer(1) = 1 Then
            ' Continue For
            'End If
            'Dim buff2(0) As Byte


            ' count = 0
            ' nstm.Flush()
            ' Do While True
            ' ReDim buffer(10023)
            ' Dim bytesRead As Integer = fstm.Read(buffer, 0, buffer.Length)
            'If bytesRead = 0 Then
            'Exit Do
            'End If

            'If count >= val Then
            'If count = 10 Then
            '   End
            'End If
            'nstm.Write(buffer, 0, bytesRead)
            'nstm.Read(buffer, 0, buffer.Length)
            'nstm.Read(buff2, 0, buff2.Length)
            'End If
            'count += 1
            'Loop
            'nstm.Read(buff2, 0, buff2.Length)


            Dim SendIt As New SendFile(foundfile, 8001, fstm)
        Next

        If My.Computer.FileSystem.GetDirectories(path).Count > 0 Then
            For Each Dir As String In My.Computer.FileSystem.GetDirectories(path)
                SendEachFileInDir(Dir, path1, nstm)
            Next
        End If


    End Sub

    Public Class SendFile
        Public Sub New(ByVal foundfile As String, ByVal port As Integer, ByVal fstm As FileStream)
            Dim count As Integer = 0
            Dim SendFileClient As New TcpClient
            Dim netsStream As NetworkStream
            Dim Buffer(10023) As Byte
            Dim buff2(0) As Byte
            Dim buffstart() As Byte = System.Text.Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes("PenSendProc")
            'Dim fstm As Stream = New FileStream(foundfile, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read)

            SendFileClient.Connect("10.0.20.1", port)
            netsStream = SendFileClient.GetStream

            Do While True
                ReDim Buffer(10023)
                Dim bytesRead As Integer = fstm.Read(Buffer, 0, Buffer.Length)
                Dim CountIt As Integer = 0

                If bytesRead = 0 Then
                    Exit Do
                End If


                Dim BufferSend(UBound(buffstart) + UBound(Buffer) + 1) As Byte

                For i = 0 To UBound(buffstart)
                    BufferSend(CountIt) = buffstart(i)
                    CountIt += 1
                Next

                For i = 0 To UBound(Buffer)
                    BufferSend(CountIt) = Buffer(i)
                    CountIt += 1
                Next

                If bytesRead < 10024 Then
                    'MessageBox.Show("jj")
                End If

                netsStream.Write(BufferSend, 0, 11 + bytesRead)
                netsStream.Read(buff2, 0, buff2.Length)
                netsStream.Flush()
                count += 1
            Loop
            netsStream.Read(buff2, 0, buff2.Length)

        End Sub
    End Class


    Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
        Dim SendItClient As New TcpClient
        SendItClient.Connect("10.0.20.1", 8000)
        Dim nstm As NetworkStream = SendItClient.GetStream
        Dim GetFolder As New FolderBrowserDialog
        GetFolder.ShowDialog()
        Dim path1 As String
        path1 = GetFolder.SelectedPath

        GetBytes(path1)
        SendEachFileInDir(path1, path1, nstm)
        SendItClient.Close()
    End Sub
End Class
```

Thankyou for your time.ddddddddddd

Comment: attache error happened / stack trace?

Comment: There is no error displayed. It just appears as though I am receiving some extra data

Comment: Just curious, why are your buffer variables initialized with two different sizes in `Process` and `ReceiveFile`?

Comment: This is just a typo - before I created this post I was playing around with buffer sizes

Comment: Does anyone have any ideas?